How to deploy a war file in tomcat10 without using tomcat10 manager
I have a war file and tomcat10 installed on a machine how to deploy that war without using the tomcat10 manager (select a file to upload). I am using ubuntu 24. I pretend to use jenkins to make the deploy for me in the future. For now I am doing the steps manually to check how it is.

Did you bother to do any research before asking? (cause it is kind of expected) see https://www.baeldung.com/tomcat-deploy-war

Small point: "I pretend..." Did you mean "I intend..."?

It is actually expected in the guidelines to "Search, and research".

You know 'deployment' means little more than copying a war to a certain directory ($CATALINA_HOME/webapps) right..?

Apparently I achieve what I wanted. Placing the war here /var/lib/tomcat10/webapps. I was all the time looking at etc/tomcat10. I don't know why so many tomcat directories.

yes, you are right! placing war file in $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/ will do the deployment. In Ubuntu $CATALINA_HOME is "/var/lib/tomcat10/webapps" :)
